# Remove multiple list elements (substrings)

Tags: python, list

I have a sorted list of directories:

`lst :=`

```
./C01
./C01/BOOST
./C01/BOOST/src
./C01/BOOST/src/template
./C01/EmployeeAdmin
./Spheres
./db01/src/scottlib # added later
./db03
./db03/src
./db03/src/examples
./db03/src/exercises
./txt2bmp
./txt2bmp/data
./txt2bmp/docs
./txt2bmp/tests
./txt2bmp/txt2bmp
./txt2bmp_COPYED
./txt2bmp_COPYED/data
./txt2bmp_COPYED/docs
./txt2bmp_COPYED/tests
./txt2bmp_COPYED/txt2bmp
./txt2bmp_cpp
./txt2bmp_cpp/doc
```

I've tried to remove all subfolder - if existing -, but i could not do it in a nice, pythonic way. I did it with loops, but this was an long, ugly and inscrutable solution...
After the deletion the list should be shown like this:

`lst2 :=`

```
./C01
./Spheres
./db01/src/scottlib
./db03
./txt2bmp
./txt2bmp_COPYED
./txt2bmp_cpp
```

The next line is the command I've tried to modify in many ways, but without success...

```
[ i for i in lst if not i.startswith(lst[0])]
```

Perhaps you have an idea to solve this in an elegant way?

Comment: Using the `re` module (regular expressions) would be quick and easy with pattern like `\./\w+$`

Comment: You want to delete the subfolders or only remove them from the list?

Comment: Oh sorry, I only want to remove them from the list.

Comment: It is possible that a folder `./db01/src/scottlib` appears in the list. I'm sorry, the question was not as precise as I wantet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does the trick

```
lst2 = [a for a in lst if '/'.join(a.split('/')[:-1]) not in lst]
for line in lst2: print line
```

Output:

```
./C01
./Spheres
./db03
./txt2bmp
./txt2bmp_COPYED
./txt2bmp_cpp
```

Comment: Your solution works good for me; Ive tested it with several lists :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can do a simple count of the path separator and use that for filtering in a *list comprehension*, keeping only items with a count of 1:

```
lst2 = [i for i in lst if i.count('/')==1]
```

Considering @Jean-FrançoisFabre's comment, you could replace `/` with `os.sep` to add some portability to the snippet.

Comment: This might not be what OP wants though.

Comment: I would use `os.sep` to make it portable. And what if the paths are absolute instead of `./`? or even relative without the `./` ? as a general case, the problem is really tricky.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `os.sep` does add some generalisation, but since we don't know how they built their list, any patch will mostly be based on assumptions.

Comment: I think the solution to count the slashes won't work if new folder will be added to the list. It is possible, that `./db01/src/scottlib`will be added... I will change the Mainquestion!

Comment: @Chris You simply run the code again. It won't snoop on your new additions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would first normalize the paths (with `os.path.relpath`), then isolate the first component, then filter to unique paths (with `set`):

```
from os.path import relpath
def strip_tail(path):
    try:
        return path[:path.index("/")]
    except ValueError:
        return path

lst2 = list(set(strip_tail(relpath(dir)) for dir in lst))
```